# Share cookies between electron and chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, electron

Is it possible to share cookies between an [electron](https://github.com/atom/electron) app and chrome?

When running an example electron app with example.com I'm setting a cookie using:

```
document.cookie = 
    'testCookie=test; expires=Fri, 6 Aug 2021 20:47:11 UTC; path=/; domain=.example.com'
```

I was expecting that when I navigate to example.com in chrome to see that my cookie was set. Again, is it possible to share cookies between electron and chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, sorry. Electron uses its own profile.